# Creating a customized installer for a java application

Tags: java, installation, customization

I want create a installer which will ask to select a path for file(access) during the installation process and then a folder will be created and the path which was selected by the user will add to a new text file inside the newly created folder.I have checked installer creating programs like INNO setup.But they are providing very few default actions.Can any one direct me in the correct direction.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use something like INNO and use default action to call scripts/code which can be as complex as you want. I guess the only benefit of using the existing installer/packaging framework is UI for individual developers. Apart from the UI you anyways have to write your processes and actions.

Comment: That means I have to create define my own UI  giving the ability for the user to select the folder and those things.Thanks for the answer.I will try it

Comment: maybe at the end of the installation by INNO, call your code to do the rest of the task - there are a lot of products which open a second window during installation to do specific stuff.

Comment: Okay I will try it.Thanks a lot